# Map certain letters to numbers in JS

Tags: javascript

I've got quite of a problem here. The image below shows music notes and their frequencies in Hz. I have made a range-slider in html ranging from 0 to 7902 which is the highest value. What I want to to is to map the actual tone (aa letter) to the current value in the slider, so I can print that out instead of just the number. My question is: How do I map these letters to their number? I want to display the letter. in a div or something.

```
<input id="frequency" name="frequency" type="range" min="0" max="7902" step="1" value="0" />
```

reference:

[image]

Comment: There is no question asked there.

Comment: have you tried anythig.Give something so that others can review your code and help you in the process

Comment: post the code you have tried till now.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What do you currently have (and/or) tried to try and get this to work? Edit the question to actually ask a question. Are you asking us how to display the letter in a p, div, a tag? Or are you wanting to display the letter as values on the slider. It's unclear what you're asking! I would suggest editing the question to be a bit more precise if you want some help!

Comment: Edited the post with a question.

Comment: @DanielPark Edited. I just want to map the letter do its number. I know html and can there for decide later how i want to display it. Its the function i need help with.

Comment: @AL-zami I dont even know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with music pitches it is normally easier to work with pitch-classes rather than note names until you actually need to display a note name. This avoids problems of enharmonic notes. You can go from frequency to pitch class with the simple formula. Then use the pitch class to get the note name you want from an array. To get the pitch class use (this has pitch 0 as `c`):

```
var pitchClass =  Math.round(12 * (Math.log2(f/16.35))) % 12
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="frequency" id="frequency" name="frequency" type="range" min="0" max="7902" step="1" value="0" />

<div class="answer">c</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.frequency').on('change', show_note);
  var notes = ['c', 'c-sharp', 'd', 'e-flat', 'e', 'f', 'f-sharp', 'g', 'g-sharp', 'a', 'b-flat', 'b']


  function show_note() {

    var f = $('.frequency').val();
    var pitchClass = Math.round((12 * Math.log2(f / 16.35)) % 12)
    var notename = notes[pitchClass];

    $('.answer').html('frequency: ' + f + ' note: ' + notename);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Did not knew about pitch-classes. One question tho, how come that soo many notes gets undefined?

Comment: @user2952238 -- sorry wasn't paying attention to negative logs. I simplified a bit. You'll need adjust your range to avoid 0 hz and should probably set a sensible minimum.

Comment: Ok, i understand. so the range should instead start on 16.35 which is C0?

Comment: and maybe not go so far as 7902 since thats almost not able to hear.

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, add more notes in increasing order:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="frequency" id="frequency" name="frequency" type="range" min="0" max="7902" step="1" value="0" />

<div class="answer">C0</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('.frequency').on('change', show_note);

var freqs = [
             {'f': 16, 'l': 'C0'},
             {'f': 32, 'l': 'C1'},
             {'f': 65, 'l': 'C2'},
             {'f': 131, 'l': 'C3'},
             {'f': 262, 'l': 'C4'},
             {'f': 523, 'l': 'C5'},
             {'f': 1047, 'l': 'C6'},
             {'f': 2093, 'l': 'C7'},
             {'f': 4186, 'l': 'C8'},
             {'f':100000, 'l': 'dummy'}
             ];

function show_note(){

 var current = $('.frequency').val();
 var ret = false;

 $.each(freqs, (key, val) => !ret && current < (val.f + freqs[key + 1].f)/2 ? ret = val.l : '');

 $('.answer').html(ret);
 
}


</script>
```